# How can a make a c program that uses 2 different processes

Tags: c, process, fork, wait

I need to make a program in c that converts a string to capitals and vice-versa
Using 2 processes, one to read from the console and write the converted
string and another to convert the string
I already have the algorithm, I just can't manage to use the fork/wait
correctly

```
void Convert(char *word){
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        if(word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
            word[i] -= 32;
        else if(word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z')
            word[i] += 32;
    }

}

void testEx4(){
char word[10000];
while(scanf("%s", word) != EOF){
        Convert(word);
        printf("%s\n", word);   
    }
```

}

Comment: This is non-trivial with two processes, since you have separate memory spaces. You would have to use shared memory (either explicit or implicit with threads). I do not see the benefit of separate processes/threads in any case, is this some kind of exercise?

Comment: @Ctx Yes, it is an exercise. Then maybe I have to use pipes?

Comment: Yes, you can use pipes, but this makes things quite complicated...

Comment: Then, what would you suggest? @Ctx

Comment: Well, that depends on the constraints of your exercise ;) If you are allowed to use _threads_, I would prefer that.

Comment: Yes, I'am allowed to use threads. Altough, I don't know how to use them correctly

Comment: This is easy: Call convert with `pthread_create(&thread, NULL, Convert, word);` (you have to declare Convert as `void *Convert(void *word)` to match the prototype of `pthread_create`) and wait for it with `pthread_join(thread, NULL)`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think it was that easy, I guess I was complicating it too much. Thank you very much for your help